# Why do some images cause requestAnimationFrame() to lag/drop framerate?

Tags: javascript

Basically the title. I was creating a smoothly scrollable gallery with a bunch of images but I noticed a ton of lag.

I was getting massive framerate drops/lag with requestAnimationFrame(). I spent hours debugging my code thinking I was infinitely adding something etc.

But then I removed a specific image, and load and behold the image was the cause of the lag. None of the other images made requestAnimationFrame() lag. I replaced the laggy image with a different image and everything works properly with no lag.

This is where I got the laggy image -> https://unsplash.com/photos/sTPy-oeA3h0

Comment: Are your other images in AVIF format as well? It's kind of unusual so maybe not as well optimized as JPEG and WebP. Or: are your other images simply smaller?

Comment: @Thomas All my images are jpgs including that one (clicking download gives a jpg instead of right clicking download for avif). Yeah my other images are smaller my second largest is 6961px by 4646px 

the laggy image is 7680px by 9600px

Comment: @Thomas I think you're right, it makes sense if it has to paint each frame then resolution would matter right? that makes sense, thank you